# Activity has leaked window?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, progressdialog, onresume

I am having one java class in that class as soon some one purchases our application then it will start downloading and progress dialog has to appear instead it goes to some other page and when i come out of the application and when i restart then it starts downloading. 
Please Help me out from this mess...

Thank you

Comment: A leaked window is caused by not dismissing a dialog in the window (i.e. Activity) it was created in.  It should be noted that if your download is cancelled, then `onPostExecute()` is not run at all, meaning you should put `pDialog.dismiss()` in your `onCancelled()` override.

Comment: Now after cancelling it still shows error as well as new error has arrived 07-16 18:59:44.261: E/AndroidRuntime(7452): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
07-16 18:59:44.261: E/AndroidRuntime(7452):  at cdl.shrihanuman3d.DownloadActivity$DownloadAsyncTask.onCancelled(DownloadActivity.java:486)
07-16 18:59:44.261: E/AndroidRuntime(7452):  at android.os.AsyncTask.onCancelled(AsyncTask.java:404)
07-16 18:59:44.261: E/AndroidRuntime(7452):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:629)

Comment: I just noticed a really big issue with your code.  You have two internal variables named `pDialog`.  One in your `DownloadActivity` and one in your `DownloadAsyncTask`.  Basically, remove all reference to the `pDialog` in your Activity.  You should create and destroy the AlertDialog from your AsyncTask

Comment: I'm sorry, but there isn't a small fix for this.  Your references to the progress dialog are really messy, so the best suggestion I can make is to remove it altogether.  Once your code doesn't throw that leaking error, go back and only create and destroy the progress dialog within your AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Check the condition for dialog, before showing.

Like this

```
if(pDialog!=null)
{
  if(!pDialog.isShowing())
{
pDialog.show();
}
}
```

and also while removing the dialog in `onPostexecute()` check for null.

if Still not works just remove the `pDialog` and try once with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Two causes for your error happen:

1. The error will happen if you're trying to show a `Dialog` after you've exited an `Activity`.
2. Also, if an unhandled Exception was thrown in your `AsyncTask`, which would cause the `Activity` to shutdown, then an open progress dialog will cause the `Exception`.

According to the Log you've posted, the error happens after you call `pDialog.show()` which might be the 1st cause I've mentioned before.

Also you are calling `finish()` in many parts of your code, maybe one of these calls are making your `Activity` to stop and leaking your `Dialog`.

You must check which one of them is finishing your `Activity` before you show the `Dialog`. A good solution is to dismiss the `Dialog` (if it's showing) before calling `finish()`.

Comment: So basically what is the solution of this prob?

Comment: @Mehdi1991 as I said, you are finishing your activity in many parts of your code by calling `finish()`, which might be causing the error. You must check which one of them is finishing your `Activity` before you show the `Dialog`. Got it? A good solution is to dismiss the `Dialog` before calling `finish()`.

Comment: thank you my friend  but still error persist::::Still getting the same error........